# How to select the selected columns in a query for a surrogate key

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a hashed surrogate key in Bigquery using the following functions as part of a larger select query. As it currently stands, the query selects all the rows from every tables joined. I want it to only include the fields selected in the select statement above it. How do I go about doing this?

Here's my query:

```
    SELECT

   ---- I WANT THE SURROGATE KEY TO SELECT THE BELOW FIELDS AND NOT THE ONES FROM INSIDE EVERY TABLE JOINED AS IT DOES PRESENTLY ----


    user_._operating_country AS _operating_country
    /* DEMOGRAPHICS */
    , user_.userId AS id
    , UPPER(address_.county) AS `state`
    , UPPER(address_.city) AS city
    , UPPER(address_.postcode) as zipcode
    , CASE UPPER(user_.gender)
        WHEN "FEMALE" THEN "Female"
        WHEN "MALE" THEN "Male"
        ELSE "Unknown"
    END AS gender
    , user_.dob AS date_of_birth

    /* PII */
    , user_.email AS email
    , user_.firstName AS first_name
    , user_.lastName AS last_name
    , user_.username AS username
    
    /* ACCOUNT */
    , user_.joinFormStatus AS join_form_status
    , account.userId IS NOT NULL AS has_account
    , account.accountType AS account_type 
    , UPPER(
        COALESCE(
            parent_promo.code, parent_promo_ref.code, promo.code, promo_ref.code
        )
    ) AS promocode 
    , COALESCE(
        parent_promo_group.description, parent_promo_group_ref.description, promo_group_ref.description, promo_group_ref.description
    ) AS channel_acquisition
    /* TIMESTAMPS */
    , user_.activationDate AS activation_timestamp
    , user_.cancellationDate AS cancellation_timestamp
    , user_.created AS user_created_timestamp
    , account.cardExpiryDate AS card_expiry_timestamp

    /* Surrogate keys */
 
 ---- THIS IS WHAT I'M CONCERNED WITH -----
    , SHA256(
        TO_JSON_STRING(
        STRUCT(
            user_
            , promo
            , promo_group
            , promo_pair
            , promo_ref
            , promo_group_ref
            , account
            , relations
            , parent_promo
            , parent_promo_group
            , parent_promo_pair
            , parent_promo_ref
            )
        )
    ) AS _surrogate_key
    , CURRENT_DATE("UTC") AS _ingestion_date
    , CURRENT_DATETIME("UTC") AS _ingestion_datetime
    , user_._scd_valid_from AS valid_from
    , user_._scd_valid_to AS valid_to

    FROM `user_` AS user_

    LEFT JOIN `account` AS account 
        ON user_.userId = account.userId 
        AND user_._operating_country = account._operating_country
        AND user_._metadata_timestamp BETWEEN account._scd_valid_from AND COALESCE(account._scd_valid_to, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
  

    LEFT JOIN `promo` AS promo 
        ON UPPER(TRIM(user_.signupPromo)) = promo.code 
        AND user_._operating_country = promo._operating_country
        AND user_._metadata_timestamp BETWEEN promo._scd_valid_from AND COALESCE(promo._scd_valid_to, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
  

    LEFT JOIN `promo_group` AS promo_group 
        ON promo.groupId = promo_group.groupId 
        AND promo._operating_country = promo_group._operating_country
        AND promo._metadata_timestamp BETWEEN promo_group._scd_valid_from AND COALESCE(promo_group._scd_valid_to, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
  

    LEFT JOIN `promo_pair` AS promo_pair 
        ON IFNULL(promo.code, RIGHT(UPPER(TRIM(user_.signupPromo)), 2)) = promo_pair.pair 
        AND promo._operating_country = promo_pair._operating_country
    
    LEFT JOIN `promo_ref` AS promo_ref 
        ON promo_pair.inviteePromotion = promo_ref.code 
        AND promo_pair._operating_country = promo_ref._operating_country
    
    LEFT JOIN `promo_group_ref` AS promo_group_ref 
        ON promo_ref.groupId = promo_group_ref.groupId 
        AND promo_ref._operating_country = promo_group_ref._operating_country
        AND promo_ref._metadata_timestamp BETWEEN promo_group_ref._scd_valid_from AND COALESCE(promo_group_ref._scd_valid_to, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
  
      
      /* Parents of children users users */
    LEFT JOIN `relations` AS relations 
        ON user_.userId = relations.userId 
        AND relations.relationType = 'CHILD' 
        AND user_._operating_country = relations._operating_country
        AND user_._metadata_timestamp BETWEEN relations._scd_valid_from AND COALESCE(relations._scd_valid_to, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
  
    
    LEFT JOIN `parent` AS parent 
        ON relations.relatedId = parent.userId 
        AND relations._operating_country = parent._operating_country
        AND relations._metadata_timestamp BETWEEN parent._scd_valid_from AND COALESCE(parent._scd_valid_to, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
  
    
    LEFT JOIN `parent_promo` AS parent_promo 
        ON UPPER(TRIM(parent.signupPromo)) = parent_promo.code
        AND parent._operating_country = parent_promo._operating_country
        AND parent._metadata_timestamp BETWEEN parent_promo._scd_valid_from AND COALESCE(parent_promo._scd_valid_to, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
  
    
    LEFT JOIN `parent_promo_group` AS parent_promo_group 
        ON parent_promo.groupId = parent_promo_group.groupId 
        AND parent_promo._operating_country = parent_promo_group._operating_country
        AND parent_promo._metadata_timestamp BETWEEN parent_promo_group._scd_valid_from AND COALESCE(parent_promo_group._scd_valid_to, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
  
    
    LEFT JOIN `parent_promo_pair` AS parent_promo_pair 
        ON IFNULL(parent_promo.code, RIGHT(UPPER(TRIM(parent.signupPromo)), 2)) = parent_promo_pair.pair 
        AND IFNULL(parent_promo._operating_country, parent._operating_country) = parent_promo_pair._operating_country
            
    LEFT JOIN `parent_promo_ref` AS parent_promo_ref 
        ON parent_promo_pair.inviteePromotion = parent_promo_ref.code 
        AND parent_promo_pair._operating_country = parent_promo_ref._operating_country
    
    LEFT JOIN `parent_promo_group_ref` AS parent_promo_group_ref 
        ON parent_promo_ref.groupId = parent_promo_group_ref.groupId
        AND parent_promo_ref._operating_country = parent_promo_group_ref._operating_country
        AND parent_promo_ref._metadata_timestamp BETWEEN parent_promo_group_ref._scd_valid_from AND COALESCE(parent_promo_group_ref._scd_valid_to, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
  
    
    LEFT JOIN `address_` AS address_ 
        ON COALESCE(parent.userId, user_.userId) = address_.userId 
        AND COALESCE(parent._operating_country, user_._operating_country) = address_._operating_country
        AND COALESCE(parent._metadata_timestamp, user_._metadata_timestamp) BETWEEN address_._scd_valid_from AND COALESCE(address_._scd_valid_to, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
  

        WHERE GREATEST(
                    user_._ingestion_date
                    , address_._ingestion_date
                    , relations._ingestion_date
                    , account._ingestion_date
                    , promo._ingestion_date
                    , promo_group._ingestion_date
                    , promo_ref._ingestion_date
                    , promo_group_ref._ingestion_date
                    , parent._ingestion_date
                    , parent_promo._ingestion_date
                    , parent_promo_group._ingestion_date
                    , parent_promo_ref._ingestion_date
                    , parent_promo_group_ref._ingestion_date
                ) > (SELECT MAX(_ingestion_date) FROM `destination_table`)
```

Comment: your where clause should remove the unwanted rows, or eventually a having

Comment: @nbk but how I do I select the selected rows for the surrogate key?

Comment: that can't be answered as nobody knows which data should be excluded, so add another where clause with AND and check the result set if all unwanted rwos are gone, if not add another